# Сколько времени выполнялась программа (Java)

Tags: java

Блок кода :

```
 long m = System.currentTimeMillis();
 System.out.println(m);
```

Выдает вот такое значение : 1482923121138

Как не пытался конвертировать и где только не гуглил,выход так и не нашел.

Мне нужно преобразовать полученное значение в секунды.
Т.е. вывести на экран время выполнения программы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

попробуйте

```
long m = System.currentTimeMillis();
// Код
System.out.println((double) (System.currentTimeMillis() - m));
```

Comment: рандомно выдает значения от 500 до 950;

Comment: Это и есть время выполнения кода, насколько я помню, в миллисекундах

Comment: насколько домножить нужно?

Comment: то есть (значение / 1000) = время в секундах

Comment: Время выполнения программы : 0 секунд
СБОРКА УСПЕШНО ЗАВЕРШЕНА (общее время: 1 секунда)

Comment: В итоге значение округляется в нижнюю сторону

Comment: подберите тип значения, например, double

Comment: сделал.Раз через раз пишет "1.0" или "0.0"

Comment: то есть попробуете System.out.println((double) (System.currentTimeMillis() - m));

Comment: вот теперь работает)

Comment: Пожалуйста, обновите код в ответе с учётом доработок.

Answer (score 9):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` - возвращает количество миллисекунд прошедших с полуночи 1 января 1970 года, это называется [UNIX-время](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F).

Чтобы посчитать сколько времени выполнялся какой-то кусок кода, нужно посчитать разницу, т.е. что-то типа:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
someMethod();
// some code
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
```

Так же часто код выполняется очень быстро, тогда надо заменить за сколько выполнится большое количество повторений этого кода.

Или не всегда за стабильное время, в этом случае надо провести несколько замеров и посчитать среднее арифметическое.

Answer (score 3):

```java
Date currentTime = new Date();   // берем дату до метода.

(метод)

Date newTime = new Date();     // берем время после метода.

long long = currentTime.getTime() - newTime.getTime(); // считаем разницу. в этой переменной будет время работы метода.
```

Answer (score 1):

Для замера воспользуйтесь методом:

```
/**
 * @param method метод для замера
 * @param timeUnit единица измерения
 * @return время работы
 */
private static long timer(Runnable method, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
    long time = System.nanoTime();
    method.run();
    time = System.nanoTime() - time;
    return TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.convert(time, timeUnit);
}
```

Использовать так:

```
long time = timer(() -> {
        System.out.println("hello world");
}, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

System.out.println(time);
```

Comment: На мой взгляд, это оверинжиниринг :)

Comment: Немного есть, зато универсально

Answer (score 1):

Я обычно делаю так:

```
long time = System.nanoTime();  
// Код, который нужно померить 
time = System.nanoTime() - time;  
System.out.printf("Elapsed %,9.3f ms\n", time/1_000_000.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы понимаете что в java измерить производительность одним разом нельзя. Причина - JIT-компиляция. Вам требуется измерять множество раз код.

Тоесть это, не совсем правильно, вот 1 000 раз измерить и на больших значениях, хорошо.

```
long m = System.currentTimeMillis();
// Код
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - m);
```

Answer (score 1):

Как замерить производительность уже только ленивый не отписался, однако остался еще один вопрос:

> Как не пытался конвертировать и где только не гуглил,выход так и не нашел.

Примените `new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());` и вы по сути сконвертируете время от эпохи в дату.

Answer (score 0):

Я замерял длительность выполнения кода следующим образом. При помощи timestamp Можно замерить длительность выполнения кода. Например посчитаем время в секундах, за которое к строке прибавим случайное число сто тысяч раз. у меня прога показала 13 сек.

```
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String line  = ""; //строка к которой мы будем прибавлять 100000 (сто тысяч) раз случайное число.
    for (int i = 0; i<100000;i++) {
        line+=Math.random();
    }
    System.out.println("Код выполняется - " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start)/1000 + " сек.");
```